# Delete all rows from a table, throws nullpointer

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to write a function that will delete every row in a given table but I'm getting a null pointer exception. Could somebody point me in the right direction? Here is the code...

```
   public void deleteall(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = tweets.getWritableDatabase();
    String delete = "TRUNCATE FROM tweets";
    db.rawQuery(delete, null);

      }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Check if `tweets` is null.

I think it's more simpler to use this call, than using rawQuery.
Your rawQuery must be parsed, but using the delete method it uses already a parametrized query.

```
db.delete('tweets',null,null);
```

Comment: Still getting a nullpointer, I'm using the count method you helped me with in another question to check if rows > 1 if it is then I'm executing that method. But I'm still getting a null pointer, I assume I'm going about this the wrong way.. is their a better way to check for a null table?

Comment: Check the `adb logcat` or `ddms` to see what causes the null pointer. I think you have some other stuff null there. http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx

Answer (score 11):

just to delete all rows, you can use following method.

```
void deleteAll()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(table_name, null, null);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext(), DataBaseHelper.DataBaseName, null, 1);
    sqLiteDatabase = dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
        sqLiteDatabase.delete(DataBaseHelper.TableName, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a null pointer exception, and then I realised that my method was not calling `db.open()` first. Added that (and `db.close()`) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have any `TRUNCATE` statement, so you must do:

```
public void deleteall(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = tweets.getWritableDatabase();
    String delete = "DELETE FROM tweets";
    db.rawQuery(delete, null);
}
```

Comment: just to delete all rows, you can use following method.

void deleteAll()
 {
  SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
  db.delete(table_name, null, null);
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is this:

```
db.delete('tweets',"1",null);
```

From Android official documentation: [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))